# menu option on image on mouse hover in html

Tags: css, html, image

I'm new in HTML/CSS and want to create movie application using html/angular js.
where user can see list of movies. movie details will be fetch from server.

when user hover the mouse on movie image, it should show menu on that image with different options to play the movie (e.g. play in media player, browser, ...)

I have tried by setting background-image in css for li tag but that will display same image for all li tag, in my case movie list will be dynamic generated and should not hardcoded in css file. it should look like below

[image]

Tried by below way

I tried by below way it was working fine for single image but when I tried multiple images using ng-repeat, it shows options for all images when I hover mouse on single image, seems that I'm doing in working way, please help. below is pseudocode.
css file

```
#frame_wrapper {
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
            z-index: 0;
            border: 1px solid #999999;
        }
        .movie_image {
            display: block;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: red;

        }
        #movie_option {
            display: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: 1;
            background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7);;
        }
        #frame_wrapper:hover #movie_option {
            display: block;
        }

<div id="frame_wrapper" ng-controller="AppController">
    <div class="movie_image">
    <ul>;
        <li data-ng-repeat="movie in movies | orderBy:'name':true">
            <a href="#"><img data-ng-src="{{movie.thumb}}"></a>
            <div id="MovieTitle">{{movie.name | uppercase}}</div>
            <div id="movie_option">
                <nav>
                    <ul style="background: green">
                        <li>
                            <a href="">PLAY    | <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>;
                            <div>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="">Play locally</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">Play on webpage</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">Play on media player</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: paste some Code or fiddle ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

```
 <ul class="movie_list">
  <li class="movie_image" data-ng-repeat="movie in movies | orderBy:'name':true">
      <a href="#"><img data-ng-src="{{movie.thumb}}" /></a>
            <div class="MovieTitle">{{movie.name | uppercase}}</div>
            <div class="movie_option">
                    <ul style="background: green">
                            <li>
                                    <a href="#">PLAY    | <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                    <div>
                                            <ul>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Play locally</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Play on webpage</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Play on media player</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                    </div>
                            </li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
  </li>
  <li class="movie_image" data-ng-repeat="movie in movies | orderBy:'name':true">
      <a href="#"><img data-ng-src="{{movie.thumb}}" /></a>
            <div class="MovieTitle">{{movie.name | uppercase}}</div>
            <div class="movie_option">
                    <ul style="background: green">
                            <li>
                                    <a href="#">PLAY    | <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                    <div>
                                            <ul>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Play locally</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Play on webpage</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Play on media player</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                    </div>
                            </li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
  </li>
  <li class="movie_image" data-ng-repeat="movie in movies | orderBy:'name':true">
      <a href="#"><img data-ng-src="{{movie.thumb}}" /></a>
            <div class="MovieTitle">{{movie.name | uppercase}}</div>
            <div class="movie_option">
                    <ul style="background: green">
                            <li>
                                    <a href="#">PLAY    | <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                    <div>
                                            <ul>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Play locally</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Play on webpage</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Play on media player</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                    </div>
                            </li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
  </li>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.movie_image').hover(
  function() {
    $('.movie_option', this).addClass('active');
  }, function() {
    $('.movie_option', this).removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

css:

```
ul.movie_list {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li.movie_image {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 180px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.movie_option ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.movie_option ul, .movie_option ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;   
}

.movie_option {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;   
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/michaelyuen/3z5cbu3f/

Comment: I tried above option, it was working fine for single image but when I tried multiple images using ng-repeat, it shows options for all images when I hover mouse on single image, seems that I'm doing in working way, please help. below is pseudocode.

Comment: As I said, you need to you unique id instead of class. If you use class, all having the same class will show images. However, if you have lots of record, I would suggest you to use javascript like:

I will modify my answer for you

Comment: I uploaded the code below the image I have attached in question.

Comment: Thanks Michael for sharing code, but still its not working as expected, it shows menu on all images if we hover on single image. can you try with multiple images using ng-repeat in "li" tag . this way <li ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3]"> < img src="image path">

Answer (score 0):

I would use a hidden `div` with all the markup to make the menu, and show and hide that with Javascript. Look at the *[OnMouseOver](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp)* event.

However, please consider the useability - or lack of - on touch screen devices. These tend to struggle with "mouse over" events.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best option if you want to use the angular is to use [ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)
dropdown.
You can use such structure

```
<div class="movie>
    <img src="path_to_img">
    <div class="menu">
        <!-- MENU MARKUP -->
    </div>
</div>
```

and on CSS

```
.menu{
   display:none;
}

.movie:hover .menu{
    display:block;
}
```

still you need to show it on mobie if you want to have it responsive friendly.

Whole element should work as a angular directive.

Comment: in above case, menu will be placed after image control and not on image.